# Cannot install Lubuntu on Mac

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, lubuntu

I am trying to install Lubuntu on a harddrive where Ubunut has been running on. The Hard Drive is in a MacBook Pro (mid 2012, 10.10.5). I installed `rEFIned` and created a bootable stick from a `Lubunutu iso`. I then tried to install Lubuntu for the first time. The first run gave me the error "Cannit install boot loader... Fatal error". 
Not very promising. 
When I started the Computer, I didnt see the Linux Distro (with Dual Boot -> rEFInd). However, I simply installed it a second time and now I can see the nice Penguin when I turn on the computer. It says "Boot Linux (Legacy) from whole disc Volume". When I click on it, the screen turns black and I see a `_`... Nothing more.

Any ideas what went wrong?